# Unable to include non-blade file with @include

Tags: laravel, laravel-3

The path to my partial view is:

```
my_bundle/views/partials/subfolder/view_name_nodots
```

I am trying to include it in a view, using:

```
@include('my_bundle::partials.subfolder.view_name_nodots')
```

But I get the error:

```
'my_bundle::partials.subfolder.view_name_nodots' does not exist.
```

If I rename the view to `view_name_nodots.blade.php`, the above `@include` works. But I don't want blade to be used in that partial file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I am to use the file name `view_name_nodots.php`. The include works when I do that.